# How to display line breaks in SharePoint comment history field

Tags: sharepoint

We have a SharePoint list setup with history enabled so the Comments field keeps all the past values. When it displays, the Comments field is void of all line breaks. However, when SharePoint e-mails the change to us, the line breaks are in there. The Description field also shows the line breaks.

So, something must be stripping out the line breaks in the read-only view of the Comments field.

Any idea on how to customize that so it retains the formatting in the detail view of the SharePoint list item?

---

Update: the stock pages with this behavior are

- /EditForm.aspx
- /DispForm.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to view the list?  A default SharePoint view (AllItems.aspx?), or a DataFormWebPart?  Something else?

If you can customize the page that displays this list in SharePoint Designer, make sure this field is set to display "Rich Text" and not just "Plain Text".

If this is the cause of your problem, then another symptom you might see is that certain symbols are displayed as their HTML codes (e.g. "&" as "`&amp;`").